# PDE of the curve shortening flow for convex curves

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, mean-curvature-flows

I'm trying study the curve shortening flow for convex curves. I'm studying for the Lectures on Mean Curvature Flows by Xi-Ping Zhu and I found difficult to understand how the got the equation 1.2 (according the numeration of the book). He used two support functions to find equation 1.2, for the first function, he got $k = \frac{1}{S_{\theta \theta} + S}$ and, for the second function, he got $\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = - k$, but he states that $\frac{\partial S}{\partial t} = - \frac{1}{S_{\theta \theta} + S}$. My doubt is why can he conclude it being that the two support functions are different? Next, the development to obtain the equation 1.2.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question - what do you mean by "two support functions are different"? There is only one support function $S$, which separately is shown to satisfy those two equations, from which 1.2 follows.

Comment: $S(\theta) = \left( \gamma( \theta), \left( \cos \theta, \sin \theta \right) \right)$ is a support function and $S(\theta, t) = \left( \tilde{\gamma} \left( \theta, t \right), - n \right)$ is the other support function

Comment: But $\theta$ is the normal angle, so $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = -\vec n$ by definition.

Comment: Oh, I thought that $\left( \cos \theta, \sin \theta \right) = n$, in this case, the second support function would be different from the first by a sign, thanks for your help! Just more one question: he states that $\left( \frac{d \gamma}{d \theta}, t \right) = \left( \frac{d \gamma}{ d s} \frac{d s}{d \theta} \right) = \frac{1}{k}$, I would like to know why the inner product is $\frac{1}{k}$? I thought that $\left( \frac{d \gamma}{ d s} \frac{d s}{d \theta} \right) = \frac{d s}{d \theta} \left( \frac{d \gamma}{ d s}, \frac{d \gamma}{ d s} \right) = \frac{d s}{d \theta}$, but ...

Comment: ... I don't understand why $\frac{ds}{d \theta} = \frac{1}{k}$, because $s (\theta) = \int_0^{\theta} || \gamma'(u) || du$ and $\frac{ds}{d \theta} = || s'(\theta)||$ by the Fundamental Theorem of calculus, so why $\frac{ds}{d \theta} = \frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: $\theta$ is the normal angle, $s$ is arclength; so $k = d \theta/ds$ is the curvature. This is often taken as a definition - the curvature measures how fast the tangent is turning as you traverse the curve at unit speed. If it's not your definition then you should be able to prove it.

Comment: hmm... Ok, I didn't know it, my definition is that curvature $k$ of a curve $\gamma$ is $k = || \gamma''(t) ||$

Comment: You mean $\|\gamma''(s)\|$. You should be able to show $n' = \theta' t$ with the chain rule and then just compare to the Frenet-Serret formulae.

Comment: I got it, thanks @AnthonyCarapetis! If possible, post your comments about the support function and the derivative of $\frac{d \theta}{d s}$ for I'm accept your answer. I will put the computation of $\frac{d \theta}{d s}$ here if anyone looks for.

 $\frac{d n}{d \theta} = \frac{(- \cos \theta, - sin \theta)}{d \theta} = (\sin \theta, -cos \theta) = - t$

 $\frac{d n}{d s} = \frac{\partial n}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial s} = -t  \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial s}$.

By the Frenet formulas, $\frac{d n}{d s} = -kt$, then $-t  \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial s} = -kt$.

Comment: By the last step, we can conclude that $\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial s} = k$, then $\frac{\partial s}{\partial \theta} = \frac{1}{k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comments from above in an answer as requested by the OP.

The two support functions $\langle\gamma, (\cos \theta,\sin \theta)\rangle$ and $\langle \gamma, -n \rangle$ are in fact the same (or correspond via reparametrization), since $\theta$ is the normal angle and thus $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = -n$ by definition.

The relation $k = d \theta/ds$ between the normal angle and the curvature is somewhat expanded upon in the last paragraph of [this wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_plane_curves).